# My Program is not printing what I want it to print

Tags: python

I have just finished this code , added my final print line and now suddenly when I test it , it doesn't print out what I want it to print.

```
import random

name=input("Welcome to this Arithmetic quiz,please enter your name:")

score = 0

for i in range(10):
    number1=random.randint(20,50)

    number2=random.randint(1,20)
    oper=random.choice('+-*')
    correct_answer = eval(str(number1)+oper+str(number2))
    answer = (int(input('What is:'+str(number1)+oper+str(number2)+'=')) == correct_answer)
    if answer == correct_answer:
       print('Correct!')
    score +=1
else:
     print('Incorrect!')
print("You got",score,"out of 10")
```

When I ever I give the right answer it still gives me Incorrect leading it to tell me that I got 0/10.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors, so you can't expect it to do anything useful.

Comment: This is Python. If your tabs show correctly on your post, your loop has an empty body because you did not indent the body.

Comment: There are no indentation problems or syntax errors (no red lines at all) it is just I don't know how to do indentation on her.

Comment: Use the space bar.  If you want to indent 4 spaces, press it 4 times.  If you can't format your code in a way that people can read, then don't bother posting at all, there's really no point.

Comment: I just did that thanks.

Comment: Ok that's better, now people can read it.

Comment: But it's still wrong, the code will always report a score of 10/10 due to what I assume must be further indentation errors.

Comment: Yes, the indentation shown in the post is very, very wrong.

Comment: OMGG.Please just forget about the indentations PythonScriptor fixes that automatically , Why the indentation kill you so much.How do I know if there are any indentation errors if no red lines are shown.

Comment: Forget the indentation?  How can we possibly know where your bugs are if your code won't even run?  One more time:  Either post your code correctly, or else please don't post here.  We aren't mind readers, and you are clearly a beginner so your bugs could be anything.

Comment: Well look down below , how come mhawke didn't cry about indentations because they can be easily fixed when entered in a python coding programming , and he solved my problem.

Comment: @PythonNooby: look again :) I eventually did shed a few tears `(;_;)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the symptoms reported I believe that your code is actually:

```
import random

name=input("Welcome to this Arithmetic quiz,please enter your name:")

score = 0

for i in range(10):
    number1=random.randint(20,50)

    number2=random.randint(1,20)
    oper=random.choice('+-*')
    correct_answer = eval(str(number1)+oper+str(number2))
    answer = (int(input('What is:'+str(number1)+oper+str(number2)+'=')) == correct_answer)
    if answer == correct_answer:
       print('Correct!')
       score +=1
    else:
       print('Incorrect!')
print("You got",score,"out of 10")
```

Note the indentation of the `else` statement is aligned with the `if`, not the `for`. Given that this line:

```
answer = (int(input('What is:'+str(number1)+oper+str(number2)+'=')) == correct_answer
```

assigns a *boolean* to the variable `answer`, not the answer that the user entered. You can do 2 things:

remove the `== correct_answer` part resulting in:

```
answer = int(input('What is:'+str(number1)+oper+str(number2)+'='))
```

or

change the `if` statement to:

```
if answer:
```

Comment: OMGG.Thank you so much.I removed the '==correct_answer' from the if statement.But why did the '==correct_answer' cause problems in the if statement ?

Comment: Because with `==correct_answer` that expression evaluates to a boolean which is then compared to expected answer which is probably an _int_. Unless the correct answer is 1 (==`True`) or 0 (==`False`) the comparison will always be False, so the answer is always considered incorrect.

Comment: Ok , thank you very much for your help mhawke , without me having to see you cry about something irrelevant *cough* *cough*. ;)

Comment: @PythonNooby: _cough cough_ back :) The indentation is highly relevant in Python. I think that it's just a posting error (which is how I was able to deduce what your actual code is), but when you want assistance from others they need to be able to understand and possibly execute your code. Because indentation is so important in Python the code that you posted has different semantics to your _actual_ code. I doubt that any tool can automagically fix the indentation because it can not tell whether indentation is deliberate or accidental.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the problems with your code:

1. You are incrementing `score` regardless of whether the answer is correct or not.  Increase the indentation of `score += 1` so that it lines up with the `print` that indicates a correct answer.
2. The `else` is bound to the `for` statement.  Indent it so that it is bound to the `if` statement.  Indent the `print` that follows it accordingly.
3. Your assignment to `answer` isn't just picking up the answer, but it's comparing it to the expected answer.  So it will be `True` or `False`.  You are then comparing that boolean value to the answer again, so of course the result if `False`.  Change the assignment to:

   ```
   answer = int(input('What is:'+str(number1)+oper+str(number2)+'='))
   ```

Probably the first two items were just posting errors, and the last one is what's preventing your code from working.

Comment: This is correct for the code as posted, however this can not be right because the OP reports that score is always 0. That can not happen with the indentation in the posted code.

Comment: I know, but I don't really feel like trying to second guess something like this, especially when OP thinks indentation is irrelevant.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , but mhawke found my problem  , my code is indented but it doesn't seem to work on the website.